# Why I obtain this "SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" when I try to perform this JDBC query?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I have some problem trying to implement a simple JDBC query into a Java application.

So I have the following query:

```
SELECT   D.*
FROM   coda_tx c, documenti_tx d
WHERE   C.FK_TIPO_DOC = 99
        AND C.FK_STATO = 1
        AND C.FK_PIVA_MITTENTE = '05779711000'
        AND C.PK_CODA = D.PFK_CODA
        AND C.CANALE='STA'
```

If I run it into **Oracle SQL Developer** it run well and I obtain 2 records as result.

So I have to implement this query into a DAO class of my application in which I definied the following method:

```
public void getListaFatturePDF(String partitaIva) {
    System.out.println("INTO ottieniListaFatturePDF()");

    Blob blobPdf;
    String sql;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("SELECT D.*");
    sb.append("FROM coda_tx c, documenti_tx d");
    sb.append("WHERE C.FK_TIPO_DOC = 99");
    sb.append("AND C.FK_STATO = 1");
    sb.append("AND C.PK_CODA = D.PFK_CODA");
    sb.append("AND C.CANALE='STA'");
    sb.append("AND C.FK_PIVA_MITTENTE = '");
    sb.append(partitaIva);
    sb.append("';");

    sql = sb.toString();

    try {
        statment = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statment.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("ResultSet obtained");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I try to perform the previous method is thrown the following **SQLException**:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:762)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1309)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:422)
    at DAO.FatturaDAO.getListaFatturePDF(FatturaDAO.java:43)
    at mainPkg.Main.main(Main.java:74)
```

Why? I think that maybe is something wrong in the SQL syntax but I am not sure about it (because if I perform the query into **Oracle SQL Developer** it works fine)  What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Tnx

Comment: Just remove `;`. `ExecuteQuery` method only receives the query without semicolon

Comment: spaces? `AND C.PK_CODA = D.PFK_CODAAND` ..

Comment: It'd be the missing spaces at the start/end of each of the string components. Try outputting `sb.toString();` before you send it, you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`executeQuery()` automatically adds a semicolon to a statement when executing it.

Change the line `sb.append("';");` to `sb.append("'");`.

Also you'll need to add spaces at the end or at the beginning of each line, your statements are invalid otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Add a white space at the end of each line so that the keyword on the next line is not clumped with it, e.g.:

```
sb.append("SELECT D.* ");
```

instead of

```
sb.append("SELECT D.*");
```

and also remove the trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is how it worked for me:
See the aligned query SELECT, FROM, UNION, etc keywords must be compatible along with the queries.
Also, see the white/very thin lines going down along these keywords. Re-aligning worked for me. Lastly, I removed the ; at the end.

All I am mentioning about .SQL files. This might be the same issue in regular java class as well.

Answer (score 0):

The semi colon was the culprit, for some reason the SQL with the ; at the end did not work in my sprint boot service.
Once I removed it, it worked fine