# Command not ended properly error - Java

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle

I have trying to connect to oracle database and fetch some records.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectionTest {

    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//connctionString";
    static final String USER = "usr";
    static final String PASS = "pwd";



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Connecting");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected");


            String queryPtyRole = "select * from emp;";

            System.out.println(conn);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryPtyRole);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String emp_id = rs.getString("emp_id");
                System.out.println("emp_id: " + emp_id);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Connection to the database is happening properly but it gives the following stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:790)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1038)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:830)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1273)
    at testPackage.ConnectionTest.main(ConnectionTest.java:38)
```

**EDIT**

Now if I change the query to:

```
String queryPtyRole = "select emp_id from emp where address_id in (select address_id from add where state_id in (1,2,3))";
```

it again gives the same error.

Comment: Just remove semicolon from your query.
Follow below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544688/why-i-obtain-this-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly

Comment: Please correct your first error - "semicolon" (as mentioned in one of the answers) - as it is misleading. Restate your question for the second problem.  Make sure that you properly recompiled (clean - build) your code after changes made.  Are you still  getting the same error after all the above?

Comment: Thanks Plirkee...after cleaning the project the error is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not using the semi colon at the end of the command:

```
String queryPtyRole = "select * from emp";
```

This should work.

Comment: This worked but not in case of nested queries.

Comment: @Leo Can you check  what error are you getting for what query because the error you posted earlier comes for SQL formation issues and the query you posted in the edit does not have any formation issue as I see.

Comment: The error is same Piyush