# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended "can't find the solution"

Tags: oracle

I've been trying to run this query i have trie all the google searches but I am not able to find what is the error in the following query it such a simple query but I am stuck

```
SELECT * FROM bank_cust_contact 
WHERE cust_state = 'Karnataka';
```

Comment: How and with which tool do you run this statement? This is one of the very few occasions where a screen shot might be helpful.

Comment: well you are providing a simple query, what might be the problem either the table is a view and contains a query that have errors or the semi column causing issue, try to replace it with `/`

Comment: try removing the ';'

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544688/why-i-obtain-this-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly

Comment: already tried...no luck

Comment: Do not struggle, change the toool, there are two that work: [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), [dbeaver.io](https://dbeaver.io/}