# Exception on simple query using Java Spring: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Tags: java, oracle

For the query below, I can use it on SQL Developer and it works fine but on the Java code I got a error about syntax, I can't find my mistake on the query below:

```
INSERT ALL 
 INTO monitor (id_monitor) VALUES('1703887') 
 INTO monitor (id_monitor) VALUES('1717417') 
 INTO monitor (id_monitor) VALUES('1717179') 
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

**Exception**

```
2020-01-27 11:45:43,185 ERROR [scheduling-1] class:State, Details: 
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [

    INSERT ALL 
     INTO monitor (id_monitor) VALUES('1703887') 
     INTO monitor (id_monitor) VALUES('1717417') 
     INTO monitor (id_monitor) VALUES('1717179') 
    SELECT * FROM dual; 
]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

The DB is Oracle.

Comment: these are two different statements. Are you missing a semicolon before the SELECT query?

Comment: On the SQL Editor appear a underlined red if I do it.

Comment: *"The DB is Oracle."* Then please only tag `oracle`. I have removed the `sql-server` tag as this has nothing to do with the question, and will only confuse readers not make your question more visible.

Comment: If you think, this is a java issue, please post your java code, otherwise please remove the tag.

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon `;` at the end - ExecuteQuery adds one automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544688/why-i-obtain-this-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly